# Examine data in windbg when a break on address (ba) breakpoint is hit

Tags: windbg, breakpoints

I'd like to create a breakpoint such that it will create another one-time breakpoint that will 'dd' a certain memory address when that memory is written to.

So when the breakpoint is hit, I'd like to run a command like:

```
  ba w4 @ESP+4 /1 ''dd [memory address of this breakpoint]''
```

Since this breakpoint is being created by another breakpoint (and could potentially be called several times), I can't specify the breakpoint number.  Otherwise I could use a pseudo register like '$bp3' to get the memory address of breakpoint #3

Would anyone have any thoughts on how to create a breakpoint command that can 'dd' the memory address of the breakpoint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can elaborate to make use of other general purpose pseudo-registers: t0..t19

```
bp your-address "r$t1=your-other-address; ba w4 @$t1 /1 \"dd @$t1;gc\""
```

Comment: If the 'your-address' breakpoint is hit twice (before the 'your-other-address' is hit), would this change the value of $t1 and cause both of the one-time breakpoints to dd @$t1 on the same address?

Thank you!!!

Comment: In that case, keep the breakpoints to minimum. Knowing you have one on 'your-address', it can also reset all other bps. Use something like 'bc1-10' in its condition (provided the 'your-address' is on bp0!) to get rid of the last 10 breakpoints that did not yet get hit.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set $t1 to 0 (to make sure ;o) and reset it to 0 in the single-shot bp. Then simply test for 0 (or for other value) and only create a new single-shot bp if a certain condition (like it being 0) is met.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will never be more than one "child" `ba` breakpoint defined, you can actually use a `@$bpN` pseudo-register by setting the "controlling" breakpoint's command to:

```
ba1 w4 /1 @esp+4 "dd @$bp1"
```

That is, specify the breakpoint number that that this new breakpoint should be assigned, and the pseudo-register for that breakpoint is still defined within the breakpoint's command.

However, if you think the controlling breakpoint will be hit multiple times and want multiple `ba` breakpoints defined, that obviously won't work because then "breakpoint 1" will just be redefined each time. But you can still do it!

The trick is to make the controlling breakpoint's command actually contain the literal address text rather than try to go through a pseudo-register. And you can do that with text aliases.

Try this for your controlling breakpoint:

```
bu @WHATEVER "aS /x ${/v:baaddy} @esp+4; .block{ ba w4 /1 baaddy \"dd baaddy\"; ad ${/v:baaddy} }"
```

When the controlling breakpoint is hit, the following happens:

- An alias is setup for the text "baaddy" with the *value* of evaluating the expression `@esp+4`.
- The `.block` ensures that alias expansion happens for what follows.
- The alias interpreter will then expand all occurrences of "baaddy" within the block, except for in the `ad` command (because of the /v switch).
- So if the value of `@esp+4` is `0x1234` the access breakpoint command literally becomes: `ba w4 /1 0x1234 \"dd 0x1234\"` with the actual address embedded in it.
- Then the text alias is deleted.

It's important to delete the text alias at the end or the next time this controlling breakpoint is hit, the alias expansion will happen *before the `aS` command*, and "baaddy" will be expanded using the *previous* value. That also means it's important that this text 
alias does not exist the first time you set the controlling breakpoint's command.